# NServiceBus SqlTransport - Where timeout manager should be run?

Tags: nservicebus

We are currently setting up NServiceBus with SqlTransport. Do we need use  distributors in our test environment ?  We have 2 clustered node are running the same application. Where timeout manager should be run in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distributor is only used for MSMQ transport, see http://particular.net/articles/load-balancing-with-the-distributor section "When to use it?".

Updated:
Timeout manager runs on all endpoints connecting to the same sql database as the transport to avoid DTC.

Here is an example config:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=nservicebus;Integrated Security=True" />
   <add name="NServiceBus/Persistence" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=nservicebus;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You need to reference NserviceBus.NHibernate, see http://particular.net/articles/relational-persistence-using-nhibernate---nservicebus-4.x for more info.